# Calculate percentage change in pandas with rows that contain the same values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using Pandas to calculate percentage change(s) between values that occur more than once in the column of interest.

I want to compare the values of last weeks workout provided they're the same exercise type to get the percentage change of (weight used, reps accomplished )

I am able to get the percentages of all the rows which is halfway what I want but the conditional part is missing - so only get the percentages if the exercise_name is of the same value as we want to compare how we improve on a weekly, bi-weekly basis.

```
ids = self.user_data["exercise"].fillna(0)
dups = self.user_data[ids.isin(ids[ids.duplicated()])].sort_values("exercise")
dups['exercise'] = dups['exercise'].astype(str)
dups['set_one_weight'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_one_weight'])
dups['set_two_weight'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_two_weight'])
dups['set_three_weight'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_three_weight'])
dups['set_four_weight'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_four_weight'])
dups['set_one'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_one'])
dups['set_two'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_two'])
dups['set_three'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_three'])
dups['set_four'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_four'])
**percent_change = dups[['set_three_weight']].pct_change()**
```

the last line gets the percentage change for all the rows for column set_three_weight but is unable to do what I want above which is find rows with same name and obtain the percentage change.

UPDATE 
**Using Group By Solution**

```
   ids = self.user_data["exercise"].fillna(0)
    dups = self.user_data[ids.isin(ids[ids.duplicated()])].sort_values("exercise")
    dups['exercise'] = dups['exercise'].astype(str)
    dups['set_one_weight'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_one_weight'])
    dups['set_two_weight'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_two_weight'])
    dups['set_three_weight'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_three_weight'])
    dups['set_four_weight'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_four_weight'])
    dups['set_one'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_one'])
    dups['set_two'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_two'])
    dups['set_three'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_three'])
    dups['set_four'] = pd.to_numeric(dups['set_four'])
    dups['routine_upload_date'] = pd.to_datetime(dups['routine_upload_date'])
    # percent_change = dups[['set_three_weight']].pct_change()
    # Group the exercises together and create a new cols that represent the percentage delta variation in percentages
    dups.sort_values(['exercise', 'routine_upload_date'], inplace=True, ascending=[True, False])
    dups['set_one_weight_delta'] = (dups.groupby('exercise')['set_one_weight'].apply(pd.Series.pct_change) + 1)
    dups['set_two_weight_delta'] = (dups.groupby('exercise')['set_two_weight'].apply(pd.Series.pct_change) + 1)
    dups['set_three_weight_delta'] = (dups.groupby('exercise')['set_three_weight'].apply(pd.Series.pct_change) + 1)
    dups['set_four_weight_delta'] = (dups.groupby('exercise')['set_four_weight'].apply(pd.Series.pct_change) + 1)
    dups['set_one_reps_delta'] = (dups.groupby('exercise')['set_one'].apply(pd.Series.pct_change) + 1)
    dups['set_two_reps_delta'] = (dups.groupby('exercise')['set_two'].apply(pd.Series.pct_change) + 1)
    dups['set_three_reps_delta'] = (dups.groupby('exercise')['set_three'].apply(pd.Series.pct_change) + 1)
    dups['set_four_reps_delta'] = (dups.groupby('exercise')['set_four'].apply(pd.Series.pct_change) + 1)
    print(dups.head())
```

I think this gets me the result(s) I want, would like someone to confirm

Comment: just group by exercise name then apply the pct_change on the groups?

Comment: @BenPap how is this function able to identify the same exercise name though and calculate the percentage change in respect to that? group by is essentially splitting the data but I don't see a method that's able to group it in the order requested though?

Comment: See below my question, I will add what I have I think this works..